# selected first item from combobox in winforms

Tags: .net, winforms

I have `comboBox` with some items. If the user does not select anything I want to select first item from `comboBox`

Right now I made selection like this

```
var selected= (CustomData)comboBox1.SelectedItem;
```

of course this works only with user selection.

I know that I can set explicitly do `SelectedIndex` like

```
if(comboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1)
  comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

but I don't know how to apply this to assign item to selected variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe in the same way after setting selected index?

```
if(comboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1)
{
  comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
  selected= (CustomData)comboBox1.SelectedItem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want duplicated code you can also connect to the selectedChanged event:

```
this.comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged);

private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      var selected = (CustomData)comboBox1.SelectedItem;
  }
```